# Synchronising local XML files with Remote FTP and Vice Versa

Tags: linux, cron, synchronization

I have developed a website in php/codeigniter that takes data from sage xml files. I have SAGE xml files on my remote sever that I am using on my website for data extraction.I am reading and writing customer data into these files.And to keep my BOTH "local" and "Remote" Content management systems up to date, I need to continuously synchronise my xml files so that I could retrieve up to date data on both systems.

**My question:**

I know there is something like "Cron jobs" that can perform schedule task from Cpanel but it requires me to have knowledge of Linux command that I haven't got . How can I perform this kind of synchronisation using PHP or Cron jobs?

Is there anyone who could guide me to achieve either using PHP or Cron Jobs as i am a new bee?I would appreciate if someone could provide a set of cron job commands.(Preferably I want to perform synchronisation after every 1 hour). Kindly help me.Thanks